# Transferring files from Android to PC: Stardew Valley folder is empty

Tags: android, stardew-valley

I've googled that I need to copy the saves folder (which looks like `User_<some_numbers>`) from the `StardewValley` folder within the phone's internal storage to my PC (Windows). But the `StardewValley` folder is EMPTY on my phone.
I can successfully save and load games on my Android, and files are not set to hidden on either device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.4, save files were stored in a folder called "StardewValley", located in the root folder of your device (Main Storage).

In 1.5, save files are in a new location. They are now located in `Android/data/com.chucklefish.stardewvalley/files/saves`.